# Не могу сделать перенос строки в string

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc

Если срабатывает if, то идет обращение к базе данных и от туда выводим столбец "team_name", записывается он в строковую переменную "resultat" и выводится в окне. Вывод получается в строку без пробелов. Нужно как-то сделать чтобы после первого названия был переход на следующую строчку и там уже следующее название команды. \n не работает.

```
String request (ResultSet rs, Object obj){
    String resultat="";
    try{
        if(obj.equals("Teams")){
            while (rs.next())
            {
                resultat+=(rs.getString("team_name") + "\n");
            }
        }           
    }
    catch(Exception e){ 
    }

    return resultat;
}
```

Если нажимаем на кнопку, то в result (JLabel окно для вывода) записывается наш результат, который получается в результате работы "string request"(код выше).

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    if(arg0.getSource().equals(button))
        result.setText(request(rs, combobox.getSelectedItem()));
}
```

Comment: попробуйте вместо \n использовать  \r\n

Comment: Не работает, пробовал так уже

Comment: Покажите код, где вы выводите свои строки

Comment: @iksuy я добавил. у меня создано JLabel окно и туда я хочу добавить текст после работы "string request"

Comment: JLabel не поддерживает мультистрочность в страндартном виде, строку надо  в виде HTML представить "<html>Line1<br>Line2</html>"

Answer (score 0):

JTextArea вместо JLabel и готово

Answer (score -1):

JLabel не поддерживает мультистрочность.
Можно сформировать строку HTML

```
`label.setText("<html>strPart1<br>strPart1</html>")`
```